# Google cloud dataflow/functions using shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

Currently I'm working on a project in GCP that uses several service projects attached to a single host project using multiple subnets for mapping different environments (classic environments development, stage and production), and I'm trying to run dataflow pipelines and cloud functions that need to connect to databases hosted on VMs in a different service project. So far I have set the service account running dataflow and cloud function with Network User role for the subnet that belongs to specific environment and in case of dataflow I'm specifying the subnetwork for the pipeline on the host project, but dataflow pipelines and cloud functions are not even able to resolve database VMs host names or connect directly using internal IP address. Does anybody know how to setup similar environment?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a *shared VPC*, which will let your accessory projects connect to the VPC of the main project.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc

From there you can use *VPC connectors* to allow your cloud functions to access internal resources. You can see this option when configuring the cloud function and hitting "more".

Comment: Seems like the serverless VPC access is not possible when considering a Shared VPC. 
See the official doc "Serverless VPC Access does not support legacy networks or Shared VPC networks".
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access